# How to set reply number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I keep receiving sms from short number and not from the number i have.

```js
const botMessage = chatGPTResponse.data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
twiml.message(botMessage);
```

Comment: This might be related to your country. In which country are you based and from which country code are you trying to send an SMS?

Comment: to a french number

Comment: And from which number?

Comment: from a finland number

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this might have happened due to the combination of the original country and target carrier, but I recommend opening a service ticket to get a definite answer for your case.